# In IoC, what is the practice for loading an object by ID?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control

I've just started learning about IoC, and I understand the general use of it, but so far, the loading process from AutoFac, Ninject and Zenject seem to be based on loading an object not based on data.

In other words, ConsoleLogger is created when ILogger is requested, which does not require any special ID's, and that makes sense.  However, what about when I want to load IUser for Id 4?  Is there a standard IoC for handling that, or are the interfaces supposed to carry methods for loading based on Id?

For instance, am I supposed to have IUserManager, with LoadUser(int id) as a method?  or is there some IoC structure for this as well?

- Thanks.

[note: I did search the web for this, but my queries did not seem to pull up relevant information and the similar question search yields too many generic questions to filter]

Answer (score 0):

IoC containers rules the way we link object's by dependencies, dependencies means some logic under Iterfaces, so IoC mostly works on Type level rather then Instance level.

Please note that types which has no any dependencies, interfaces as well as special scope requirements may be legally created by using "new" keyword for e.g. Data Transfer Objects (dto's).

In your case, you probably need a some kind of factory that can realize by parameters what kind of object caller is needed.

However, I'll suggest to you separate data from business logic as much is it can be separated.